# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'output_names'. Not toco problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

What am I doing wrong?

https://repl.it/@zbitname/outputnamesproblem

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np

    def random_generator():
        while True:
            yield ({"input_1": np.random.randint(1, 10000), "input_2": np.random.randint(1, 10000)}, {"output": np.random.randint(0, 1)})

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.tanh))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

    model.build((1000, 2))

    categories_train = random_generator()

    model.compile(
        optimizer='sgd',
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

    model.fit_generator(
        generator=categories_train,
        use_multiprocessing=True,
        workers=6,
        steps_per_epoch=10000
    )
```

### Actual results

OS: Windows 10

```
python.exe --version
> Python 3.6.7
python.exe -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.VERSION)'
> 1.12.0

python.exe bug.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 21, in 
    metrics=['accuracy']
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpointable\base.py", line 474, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 600, in compile
    skip_target_weighing_indices)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 134, in _set_sample_weight_attributes
    self.output_names, sample_weight_mode, skip_target_weighing_indices)
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'output_names'
```

OS: Ubuntu

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"

$ python3.6 --version
> Python 3.6.8
$ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.VERSION)'
> 1.12.0

$ python3.6 bug.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 21, in 
    metrics=['accuracy']
  File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py", line 474, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 600, in compile
    skip_target_weighing_indices)
  File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 134, in _set_sample_weight_attributes
    self.output_names, sample_weight_mode, skip_target_weighing_indices)
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'output_names'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a sequential model, which can only have one input and one output, with a linear structure (sequential). Your generator produces data for two inputs and one output. This is of course incompatible, and Keras tries to get the names of the inputs/outputs from your model but sequential doesn't support multiple inputs or outputs.

So solution is to make a proper model using the Functional API, or to rewrite your generator to have one input/output without names.

Comment: I changed the code, now there is 1 input. The error is the same.
And in tensorflow docs example (Sequential.fit_generator) has 2 inputs and 1 output. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Sequential#returns_21

Comment: @AlexKheben What changes did you make to the code? Also the TF Keras documentation is wrong, Sequential doesn't support multiple inputs/outputs, and your model doesn't anyways.

Comment: I changed `({"input_1": np.random.randint(1, 10000), "input_2": np.random.randint(1, 10000)}, {"output": np.random.randint(0, 1)})` to `({"input_1": np.random.randint(1, 10000)}, {"output": np.random.randint(0, 1)})`

Comment: I understand that Sequential doesn't support multiple inputs/outputs, but I don't understand how I can write the correct code...

Answer (score 0):

Combine this with @Matias Valdenegro's answer. You can't use `Sequential` models with multiple inputs.

The problem is that you're passing the data with names, which aren't defined for your model.

Just pass the data in the correct order (for a model that supports multiple outputs) and it's enough:

```
def random_generator():
    while True:
        yield ([np.random.randint(1, 10000), np.random.randint(1, 10000)], 
                np.random.randint(0, 1))
```

For a sequential model, only one input and one output are valid:

```
yield np.random.randint(1, 10000), np.random.randint(0, 1)
```

Comment: This won't work as Sequential models can't have multiple inputs.

Comment: I changed `({"input_1": np.random.randint(1, 10000), "input_2": np.random.randint(1, 10000)}, {"output": np.random.randint(0, 1)})` to `yield np.random.randint(1, 10000), np.random.randint(0, 1)`
https://repl.it/@zbitname/outputnamesproblem
And got the same error...

Comment: The problem may be in `model.build((1000, 2))` (Calling this doesn't make sense to me) or in `using_multiprocessing=True`, this is not compatible with yield generators, only with `keras.utils.Sequence` objects.

Comment: I changed `model.build((1000, 2))` to `model.build((1000, 1))` and got the same error... And I removed line with `using_multiprocessing=True` and got the same error... Why that happened with me? :)

Comment: Why are you calling model.build? This is totally different from everything I know....

Comment: Because if remove this line `model.build` TF throws exception `NotImplementedError: 'fit_generator' is not yet enabled for unbuilt Model subclasses`

Comment: Ah.... TF Keras.... you may try real Keras. Something strange is that your generator is not generating "batches", you need something with at least 2 dimensions, batch size and input_features. You also need to specify the input shape in your first layer.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielMöller!
I found solution by your advice :)
First layer must contains `input_shape` and `batch_size`. And generator must yield 2 `np.array` (1 input and 1 output). It works for me :)